# Pop up menu to show detail view of contact in contact manager

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have queried data from DB depending on user input and viewed that on a table.

There is a column in my table, it will include id of each row as a link.
When I click that link it should show a pop up menu with full details of that particular row contact.

I want to pass that id to new pop and query full details from DB and show that in the pop up. Please help me with this.

Following is my current table population depend on queried data:

```
<tr valign="middle">
                    <td><?php echo $row["last_name"];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["calling_name"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["designation"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["agm_branch"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["dgm_branch"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["office"]; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="<?php echo $row["id"];?>" value="Details" onClick="showpopup()"></td>
                </tr>
```

Now I need to write appropriate code in this java script
function:

```
function showpopup() {

    //get passed variable if any (id)
    //include database config details
    //query data base depend on passed id
    //show the results on form or table
    //close button

}
```

Comment: will the pop up allows the user to edit the details? if it doesn't, maybe try to put the id of the rows in tr elements.. create a function that will pull data of tr(use id as reference) child(td's) .. and pass it on your created form..

i'd given you the idea.. maybe try reading so you can learn more..

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on Javascript/Jquery but here's some changes i would make

1. Put the id as a argument to your JS function

   ```
   function showpopup(id){
   ...//your code here
   }
   ```

   This means that you also need to echo in the call of the function

   ```
   onClick="showpopup(<?php echo $row["id"];?>)">
   ```
2. You said you want to query more details. If you haven't got the details on this page ready to go then you can use an ajax call to a php script that can get the details and return the data.

Some reading:

[jQuery ajax calls](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

[JSON syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)